# Ejercicio sobre Lambdas

Tags: java, eclipse

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;


    public class Arreglo {

        public void ordenar(){
            List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            lista.add("Mitocode");
            lista.add("Code");
            lista.add("Mito");

            Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<String>(){

                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.compareTo(02);
                }
            });

            for (String elemento : lista){
                System.out.println(elemento);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Arreglo app = new Arreglo();
            app.ordenar();
        }

    }
```

Me salen los siguientes errores: * import java.util.Comparator; (fila 3)
* new ArrayList<>() (fila 10)
* Comparator (fila 15)
Si me pueden ayudar por favor compañers no tengo idea del por que de estos errores

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes que estas cogiendo la variable 02 en lugar de o2

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class Arreglo {

    public void ordenar(){
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add("Mitocode");
        lista.add("Code");
        lista.add("Mito");

        Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<String>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });

        for (String elemento : lista){
            System.out.println(elemento);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Arreglo app = new Arreglo();
        app.ordenar();
    }

}
```

Comment: no me habia dado cuenta de ese error. Pero igual los otros errores siguen saliendo...

Comment: Lo he compilado y ejecutado sin problemas revisar la compilación del Java que sea correcta o la configuración del Eclipse.